# Paste different values using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to AutoHotKey, but I think this scenario is best suited to use AutoHotKey.
I have to repeatedly paste 2 values in 2 different columns in a application,
e.g. I have to paste value1 in cloumn1 and value2 in column2.....
so I need a script to paste value1 when I press Q and paste value2 when I press W (as they are close to tab key).

Thanks
Kiran.

Comment: Are those two values always the same or variable ?

Comment: the 2 values are always same, the application does not allow me to save the row, without filling both the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) can accomplish this.

```
q::Send, value1
w::Send, value2
```

However, you may also want to use [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) for your application or possibly use some modifiers on your keys just in case you actually need to type q or w in the spreadsheet or in another application.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN ;Microsoft Excel
    !q::Send, value1 ;Alt + q
    !w::Send, value2 ;Alt + w
#IfWinActive
```